# Formatting php echo with null values

Tags: php, implode, notnull

Let's say I have a php array called `$t` with 5 elements in it. For demonstration purposes, let's call it `$t = [a,b,c,d,e]`.

I want to **echo** all elements in parenthesis like this:
`(a, b, c, d, e)`. However, I want this parenthesis format to hold if there are null values in the array `$t`.

For example, if `c` and `d` are null in the array, it should echo `(a, b, e)`. What's an efficient way of doing this without trying every possible permutation (impossible with large array sizes).

I have tried:

```
echo "("   
for($j=0; $j<5; $j++){
    if(!empty($t[j])){
        echo " $t[j], ";
    }
}
echo ")"
```

But this leaves a comma at the end, and even then I'm not sure if it accounts for every possible case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works. You just have to remove the trailing comma when you are done. Use `rtrim()` for that.

Comment: `array_filter` and `join` are your friends…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works pretty well:

```
<?php

function is_not_null($v) { return !is_null($v); }
$t = ['a', 'b', null, null, 'e'];
echo '('.implode(',', array_filter($t, 'is_not_null')).')';
```

**Result:**

(a,b,e)